# If condition on modulo, failing logical condition?

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement, modulo, fractions

I wanted to check if a fraction 2 4 (for example) can be simplified to 1 2!!
However logical condition fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,b,live=1;
  printf("\n\nInput integers for fraction:");
  scanf(" %d%d",&a,&b);
  while(live){  
        if(!(a%2 && b%2)){
            a/=2;
            b/=2;
        }else if(!(a%3 && b%3)){
            a/=3;
            b/=3;
        }else if(!(a%5 && b%5)){
            a/=5;
            b/=5;
        }else if(!(a%7 && b%7)){
            a/=7;
            b/=7;
        }else live--;

   }
   printf("Simplified Fraction is %d/%d",a,b);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want `a%2==0...`

Comment: Could do `while ((a%2 == 0) && (b%2 == 0)) { a/=2; b/=2; } while ((a%3 == 0) && (b%3 == 0)) { a/=3; b/=3; } ...`.  Now all set-up for a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `a%2` is equivalent to `a%2 != 0`, i.e. it tests if `a` is *not* divisible by 2.  From [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Laws), the condition `if(!(a%2 && b%2))` is equivalent to `if(!(a%2) || !(b%2))` or `if((a%2 == 0) || (b%2 == 0))`, which is not what you want.

You really want to test `if((a%2 == 0) && (b%2 == 0))` -- that is, if *both* are divisible by 2, not if *either* is divisible by 2.  Writing it this way is also much less confusing.

And it should also be obvious that in order to simplify any fraction, you need to test for all possible prime factors, which is impossible to do with a finite number of `if` statements.  The recommended way of doing this is to use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to determined the greatest common divisor of the numerator and denominator, and then you divide both by the GCD to get the fraction in reduced form.

Comment: @niCk Certianly the other `if()`s need the same update. `}else if((a%3== 0) && (b%3 == 0)){` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`(!(a%2 && b%2))` will yield true even if only one of `a%2` or `b%2` holds.

Have a look at the following example:

3/4 -> a%2 == 0, b%2 == 1 -> (a%2 && b%2) == 0 -> (!(a%2 && b%2)) == 1

You are looking for `(a%2 == 0 && b%2 == 0)` instead of your condition, and similarly for other conditions.

Comment: @niCk are you separating your numbers with a space?

Answer (score 1):

An "after an accepted answer" answer.

This does not detail the issues with OP's code nicely like @Adam Rosenfield, but does address the larger OP desire of "I wanted to check if a fraction 2 4 (for example) can be simplified to 1 2!!" in a *general* way.

Use the Euclidean Algorithm to find the greatest-common-denominator, then divide `a,b` by it.  No need to generate prime number list.  Very fast.

```
// Euclidean Algorithm
unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  while (b != 0) {
    int t = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = t;
  }
  return a;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a, b;
  for (;;) {
    printf("\nInput positive fraction like 12/30: ");
    if (scanf("%u/%u", &a, &b) != 2)
      break;
    unsigned g = gcd(a, b);
    a /= g;
    b /= g;
    printf("Simplified Fraction is %u/%u", a, b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the logical or issue identified by others, you also have an infinite loop with your `while` condition. You don't need (or want) to loop with your current code. Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int a, b;
  printf ("\n\nInput integers for fraction:");
  scanf (" %d%d", &a, &b);
  while (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0)
    {
      a /= 2;
      b /= 2;
    }
  while (a % 3 == 0 && b % 3 == 0)
    {
      a /= 3;
      b /= 3;
    }
  while (a % 5 == 0 && b % 5 == 0)
    {
      a /= 5;
      b /= 5;
    }
  while (a % 7 == 0 && b % 7 == 0)
    {
      a /= 7;
      b /= 7;
    }

  printf ("Simplified Fraction is %d/%d", a, b);
}
```

Output(s) with your given input(s)

```
Input integers for fraction:2 4
Simplified Fraction is 1/2

Input integers for fraction:8 24
Simplified Fraction is 1/3
```

Comment: `||` and not `&&`?  Also what if 12 24 entered?

Comment: You'll need to check for that, at the moment it will give you 2 4.

Comment: "You don't need (or want) to loop" looks like the wrong way to go.  It is the looping that is meant to take in 4 8 and eventually get to 1 2.

Comment: @niCk Changed it to support your other test case, I also tested that 8/24 simplifies to 1/3.